# Problema con BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-studio, navigationview, bottombar, navigation

Cuando se selecciona un ***item*** del menú este debería resaltarse para hacer notar que está seleccionado.

Eso funciona hasta que implemento el `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

cuando hago esto sigue funcionando la barra pero el resaltado ya no funciona, siempre se queda resaltado el mismo elemento.

**Mi clase**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomBar = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        bottomBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch(item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.action_home:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContainer, new HomeFragment()).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_profile:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContainer, new ProfileFragment()).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_search:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContainer, new SearchFragment()).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


}
```

**XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items"
    />
```

Comment: Cual es el código que utilizas para resaltar el item seleccionado?

Comment: El ítem se resalta solo al tocarlo, pero al agregar el listener deja de hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ya lo solucioné

La solución fue cambiar el return de `false` a `true`

```
bottomBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.action_home:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContainer, new HomeFragment()).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_profile:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContainer, new ProfileFragment()).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_search:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContainer, new SearchFragment()).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```